# Assert that object retrieved from API is compaatible with type alias

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I am running a service using typescript that fetches data from an external API and later treats it to make DB insertions.

I am defining a type alias for the expected JSON string to be retrieved from the API, example:

```
type NearEvent = {
   name: string;
   score: number;
};
```

When I receive the JSON from the API, I have to assign it to a variable of NearEvent type:

```
let data: NearEvent = JSON.parse(apiResponse);
```

How can I ensure that the parsed object will match the defined type alias? In case the parsed object contains more properties than the defined type, is it possible to ignore them and make the data variable only have the properties assigned to the type alias?

Comment: Why do you care if there are extra properties?

Comment: You are saying "assert" and "ensure" and in TypeScript those would be different.  "Assert" is you just *telling* the compiler that it's the right type, but "ensure" is presumably *testing* it somehow.  And in either case, extra properties don't violate the type, and suppressing them would involve runtime code that needs more than just a TS type definition on which to operate.  If you could provide a [mre] with more of your use case (what do you expect to see if bad values come back from `apiResponse`? what code do you have that cares about excess properties?) then maybe I could look more.

Comment: If you decide to [edit] with more info and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz so I will be notified.